# Redirecting to file on network drive from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I need to open a file that is in the network location from a asp.net page. I have a service method that returns the path of the file.

string fpath=string.empty;
fpath=service.GetDocumentPath();

The path of the file returned will be fpath="\myserv1\downloads\xyz.pdf"

How do I redirect users to fpath?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the end user have access to that path?  If so, then `Response.Redirect` is a simple way to do the trick.  If not, then you'll need your code to read in the file and stream it to the client.

Comment: Yes. end user will have access to that path. Problem is if the path returned is fpath="\myserv1\downloads\xyz.pdf"
it is appending to the URL like http://localhost/application/myserv1/downloads/xyz.pdf which is wrong path

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have to add network disk location manually? looks like fpath="z:\"+service.GetDocumentPath();